# Deleting both values from array if duplicate using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

how to delete the duplicate value from the array.

```
var list =[1,1,5,5,4,9]
```

my result will be

```
var list =[4,9]
```

how can I do by using lodash

Comment: Have you tried anything? The lodash documentation is a good place to start

Comment: Plain JS filter or reduce too

Comment: i tried with this `_.uniqBy` but i need to delete the duplicate value from the `list`

Answer (score 3):

You could check the index and last index of the actual value.

```js
var list = [1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 9],
    result = list.filter((v, _, a) => a.indexOf(v) === a.lastIndexOf(v));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank u for replay @Nina Scholz this want to happen in click function. if the value twice I want to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `_.uniqBy()`

```
  _.uniqBy(list ,function(m){
         return  list.indexOf(m) === list.lastIndexOf(m)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
var list =[1,1,5,5,4,9];

let result = list.reduce((a, b) =>{
  a[b] = a[b] || 0;
  a[b]++;
  return a;
}, []).map((e, idx) => e==1? idx: undefined).filter(e => e);

console.log(result);
```